# The Function always take the last return

Tags: simulation, anylogic, modeling

I create a Function for the setuptime. In the delay time in my service Block i write: f_getDuration(agent, v_Predecessor)
v_Predecessor is my variable typ agent and i write this in on exit: v_Predecessor = agent;

But the if function are not working. The service Block does only take the last return 10. why does it not accept my function?
Oberteil, Unterteil, Ring and Halteteil are my Agents.
CurrentAgent and predecessor are Arguments Type Agent
This is my function:

```
if (currentAgent == Oberteil && predecessor == Unterteil) {
    return 45;
} else if (currentAgent == Oberteil && predecessor == Halteteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent == Oberteil && predecessor == Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Unterteil && predecessor == Oberteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Unterteil && predecessor == Halteteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent == Unterteil && predecessor == Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Halteteil && predecessor == Oberteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent == Halteteil && predecessor == Unterteil) {
    return 40;
}else if (currentAgent == Halteteil && predecessor == Ring) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Ring && predecessor == Oberteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Ring && predecessor == Unterteil) {
    return 45;
}else if (currentAgent == Ring && predecessor == Halteteil) {
    return 45;
}
return 10;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't understand this very much.. but if Oberteil is an agent Type this  means that the == is wrong

instead you should do

```
if (currentAgent instanceof Oberteil && predecessor instanceof Unterteil) {
etc...
```

Otherwise if this belongs to some kind of loop and Oberteil and Unterteil are actual agents that are defined, then you should do

```
if (currentAgent.equals(Oberteil) && predecessor.equals(Unterteil)) {
```

Try those

The answer from @felix is wrong, and you don't need the else before the return 10... since the return is only executed if all the previous conditions are false

Comment: FYI: if you do not fully understand "==" vs ".equals()" I strongly recommend this video, fantastic resource: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AoUVdLWLFQw

Comment: In short: only ever use "==" on primitive types like int & double. For *anything* else, use `.equals()` and you will be good 99.9% of cases :)

Answer (score 1):

Right now, the function will always return 10 because this is not part of the "if-else" block (it overwrites the return values). If you only want to return "10" if the other conditions do not hold, put an "else" before "return 10;"

Comment: First of all, thank you for the fast answer. But now the Block output only the same agent.